# GridView ItemClick event not working?

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp

I am working on a UWP application, trying to implement `ItemClick` event on a `GridView`, however, when I click on an Item, nothing happens.

The relevant code is below:

**Book.xaml:**

```
<Page.DataContext>
        <vm:BookViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>

 <GridView Grid.Row="1"           
          Padding="18"           
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BookViewSource}}"           
          IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
          ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.BookGroups_OnItemClick}">
```

**BookViewModel.cs:**

```cs
public void NavigateToDetails(string url)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.DetailPage), url);
}

public void BookGroups_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{

    var bookHeader = (BookGroup)e.ClickedItem;
    NavigateToDetails(bookHeader.url);
}
```

I would really appreciate your help, thank you!

**EDIT** **: Book.xaml GrdivView source:**

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1"           
          Padding="18"           
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BookViewSource}}"           
          IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
          ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.BookGroups_OnItemClick}"
          >
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="250" Height="250" >
                <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#AA000000">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="12" Foreground="White"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="-12,0,0,0"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally as I deleted the following part from Book.xaml, t**he item click works fine:**

```
<GridView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="-12,0,0,0"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</GridView.GroupStyle>
```

I did not find out what caused the problem, but now it works.
**Thank you for your help and time :)**

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your code 1:1 into a new project and the `NavigateToDetails` method does get called. Please try to put a breakpoint in the method to see if it gets hit. If it does, there might be a problem with the `NavigationService`. Otherwise, the problem is very likely in the `GridView.ItemTemplate` - it may be possible that there is a control that handles the click event so that it doesn't bubble up to the `GridView` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I put breakpoints into both NavigateToDetailes and BookGroups_OnItemClick, but they were never hit. I added the full GridView source, also I do not see where the problem should be inside ItemTemplate.

Comment: You are right, in this case it should not matter. Could you try creating a simple project with minimum code to see if it works there? Also, close Visual Studio, got to the project folder, delete `obj` and `bin` folders, then open Visual Studio and do Build -> Clean solution and Build -> Rebuild solution and see if it doesn't help.

Comment: Rebuilding the solution unfortunately did not work.  I tried to put the code into a small project and the same here- ItemClick does not work, breakpoint is not hit.